# Creating a table with dynamic number of columns using Text::Table

Tags: perl

I want to make a program that ask the user for some inputs (which I'm saving in an array) and then create a table with those inputs as column names, but I don't know how to create the columns dynamically.

I'm currently using the [Text::Table](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Table) module, it would be great to achieve this with this module.

This is an example array I will get from the user input:

```
my @columns = ("TIME", "P1", "P2", "B1", "P3");
```

This is how I'm making the table manually:

```
my $table = Text::Table->new(
    {title => 'TIME', align_title => 'center'},
    {title => ' P1 ', align_title => 'center'},
    {title => ' P2 ', align_title => 'center'},
    {title => ' B1 ', align_title => 'center'},
    {title => ' P3 ', align_title => 'center'}
);
```

Comment: Can you post what you've got so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of strings; to convert it to an array of hashrefs where each hashref is a [column spec](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Table#Columns-as-Hashes) you can use `map`:

```
use Text::Table;

my @columns = ("TIME", "P1", "P2", "B1", "P3");
my @col_spec = map { { title => $_, align_title => 'center' } } @columns;

my $table = Text::Table->new(@col_spec);
```

Comment: Is is possible to change the header properties like, for example, alignment?